# Adding data to an existing model

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, model

Im new to coding. Sorry if this is a newbie question but i am a little lost.

I have a model that returns a stored procedure and saves to the model accordingly, now i want to add data to a field of the model later on. Basically my model is an array of objects but when im adding a new array its showing on each object the whole array and its the same in each object.. i.e

```
[0] = Name
    = Country
    = Type
```

Now i have another property that should have CurrentPosition i.e dynamically e.g 1 next property should have 2 etc etc...

I created this bit of code

```
CurrentStep = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["currentStepPosition"];
int stepCount = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentStep);
List<int> stepCountList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i <= stepCount; i++)
{
    stepCountList.Add(i);
}
```

This above outputs an array of numbers i.e 1,2,3,4,5 so on so on...

But when I add this to my model for each object my model has the above properties but instead of giving each property a unique `CurrentPosition` i.e 1 and so on for each object, It just shows the whole of the array in each object...

How can I overcome this?

###EDIT to include adding to model###

```
    Error = model?.Error == null ? null : new BrokenRule()
    {
        Message = model.Error.Message,
        Name = model.Error.Name,
    };
   
    RecipeStages = model?.Processes?.Select(obj => new GetReleasedRecipeStepsModel()
    {
        StepId = obj.StepId,
        StepType = obj.StepType,
        StepOrder = obj.StepOrder,
        StepName = obj.StepName,
        NumberOfProperties = obj.NumberOfProperties
        //CurrentStepPosition = currentStepConverted
    })?.ToArray() ?? new GetReleasedRecipeStepsModel[] { };
```

Is there a way to iterate over the model? to add the single property data in? before it gets pushed to the view?

Comment: Could you include the code where you add it to your model. The error probably lies there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Select` method has a overload that receives the index of each item. So you can use that to compute your `CurrentStepPosition` like so:

```
RecipeStages = model?.Processes?.Select((obj, index) => new GetReleasedRecipeStepsModel()
{
    StepId = obj.StepId,
    StepType = obj.StepType,
    StepOrder = obj.StepOrder,
    StepName = obj.StepName,
    NumberOfProperties = obj.NumberOfProperties
    CurrentStepPosition = index + 1
})?.ToArray() ?? new GetReleasedRecipeStepsModel[] { };
```